# IAsyncResult interface and AsyncCallback missing in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Today I installed .NET Core on mac to code some c# and I found out that IAsyncResult interface and AsyncCallback delegate are not supported in .NET Core, I used to use them to call sync methods asynchronously. so the question is , are they deprecated? or should I use Task<>s in .Net core?

Comment: Deprecated since 2010 actually - Tasks have replaced the APM model and newer libraries (ie .NET 4+)  simply *don't* have Begin/End methods. Even service proxies are generated using task-based methods since 2012.

Comment: Except what @PanagiotisKanavos commented, you should notice that even many sync methods are removed, and only async versions remain. So that you should use async/await throughout your code base whenever possible.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks a lot